# Stop/Kill a running Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I noticed I have multiple functions running but never ending because they never get to the `context.done()` call. (This is a NodeJS function).

**How can I stop these running functions without having to delete the entire function?**

- Disabling the function in the Manage tab prevents it from starting more, but doesn't end existing instances.
- Kudu doesn't give me access to TASKKILL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have the ability to simply restart the Function App site, which will kill any functions (Function App Settings > Go To App Service Settings > Restart).

If you are running on a dynamic plan, please make sure you have upgraded to the latest version of the runtime, as a timeout feature is now in effect and will prevent functions from executing indefinitely.

Comment: I am updated to the latest 1.0 version and I am getting instances of executions that havent stopped for some time.. stopping - starting the site / restarting the site or even killing the processes from kudu interface did not make the instances go away

Comment: @frictionlesspulley can you have a new question with more details about what you're seeing? When you say "instances" are you referring to individual function executions?

Comment: I created a question with screenshots of the monitor log here http://stackoverflow.com/q/40686039/314763

Answer (score 9):

For automation purposes, you can use the [**Azure CLI 2.0**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) (*local azure shell*) which makes this so much easier than clicking around in the portal blades.

This also works in the [portal cloud shell if so desired](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview).

#### Option #1: Restart Entire Function App (*via Azure CLI*)

```
az functionapp restart --name <functionappName> --resource-group <resourceGroup>
```

You can also restart the function app by killing the running `w3wp.exe` process - there is a watchdog that will automatically restart it.

#### Option #2: Restart IIS Worker Process (*via Powershell*)

```
@powershell kill -name w3wp
```

**Kudu** will allow you to do this manually via **Debug Console** and entering the command above or clicking thru **Process Explorer->Properties->Kill**.

> **Note**: Killing the IIS worker process is all that is required as any spawned child processes will also be terminated (*dotnet.exe, node, etc.*)

Answer (score 3):

This is the order of clicks starting from the portal home page to restart a function app in azure:

-> **Function Apps** (Found on the very left-hand sidebar, or on dashboard)

-> **yourFunction** (mine is called 'myFunction')

-> **Platform Features** (found near the top right of the screen)

-> **All Settings** (found under the General Settings section)

-> **Restart** (found near the top of the screen)

Answer (score 1):

It seems the portal has been updated as I couldn't find the Restart button using the given instructions.

As of 17/7/2020 you can restart a Function app by navigating to the App Service page then clicking the Restart button which is found in the Toolbar:

[image]