# Stopping / Killing Azure Functions Running Instances on Consumption Plan

Tags: azure, azure-functions

How do u kill azure function runnable instances (executions) on a Comsumption Plan (previously known as Dynamic Plan).

I am running the azure function on a runtime version of 1.0.

- Few (some not shown in the log in the screenshot below) were running past the FIVE MINUTES functionTimeout threshold (check the one with DOTTED status).
- There were however few instances that DID get killed AS expected  when they reached the FIVE MINUTES THRESHOLD (check the one with CROSSED status)

[image]

**What I tried:**

- As suggested in this SO question [Stop/Kill a running Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39935118/314763) I restarted the website hosting the azure function
- I even stopped / started the website just to be sure
- I killed the processes from kudu interface but the logs still keep showing there was a rouge instance.
- Process explorer showed 32 Threads but all of them were in WAITING status. Nothing was running from what I could observe.

**Finally**

- I deleted the website and moved over a App Service Plan based function since that seems to be the only option azure functions which need flexible timeouts.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the screenshot! That was helpful. This doesn't mean your function is actually running, but that, for some reason, the completion was never signaled. We'll investigate this and provide an update.

Comment: By the way, could you please share your function app (site) name, either directly or indirectly (as documented here https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)?

Comment: I deleted the azure function in question. Would sharing site name still help ?

Comment: It would. We can look at some logs to see if we can find something that would explain the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a monitoring bug, and although it looks confusing, would have no impact on the runtime behavior.

I have opened an issue to track this [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/916) and it will be updated as we make progress.

Thank you for your patience with this and for reporting the problem!

Comment: I got the same issue with timer triggered azure function. The azure function is *NOT long running* AND on an *App Service plan*. 
The schedule was set to run every 4 minutes but the continuous run prevents further triggers of the schedule