# Persistent gray and loading screen in Azure Functions UI

Tags: azure, azure-functions

For the past 20 hours, any click to open any Azure Function app in the Azure Portal UI results in this perpetually gray and loading screen. I have tried hard refresh, using another browser, logging out of the Azure Portal, deleting the resource group and spinning up a new one, and creating a new resource group in a different subscription, and using the Azure CLI to stop it. Has anyone encountered this? This behavior is limited to Azure Functions. Thank you for any ideas.

[image]

I have also tried the steps in [Stop/Kill a running Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39935118/stop-kill-a-running-azure-function), which include using Kudu to manually stop processes, without success.

Comment: What the Runtime Stack you use? Does you still in this loading page?

Comment: @BowmanZhu Runtime stack is Node, version 2. Yes, still loading...

Comment: Where do you create this function? On portal or on Visual Studio Code or Others? It keeps on loading may be caused by loading npm dependencies. I meet a similar problem like this before, It takes so much time to load but finally it loaded. I am not sure this is the cause of your problem but this is a possible situation.

Comment: @BowmanZhu I attempted to create it in the portal -- it should not have npm dependencies beyond what is in a blank function app because I have not been able to access any part of the function UI.

Comment: This may be due to network speed reasons. If you do create an Azure Function, but for some reason you can't check and modify your code files, then you can choose kudu
Check and modify your code above, because the Azure Function files are deployed on kudu.

Comment: You can use the web link to go to kudu directly, as all Azure Function names are unique. The format of the url: https://[yourFunctionAppName].scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole. And the file of your function is under the site/wwwroot/[functionName]

Comment: Are you still experiencing the issue  ?

Comment: Any updates on this ?

Comment: @DixitArora-MSFT It continues to spin. I logged a support ticket with Microsoft and they responded with an offer to help figure out the issue.